# Trouble Implementing Google Classroom API with Swift for iOS: Possible missing bridging header file

Tags: ios, swift, google-classroom

I am trying to implement the Classroom API with my iOS App using Swift, and have been following the sample code for Swift on the Classroom API support pages.  This has recently been updated.  I have followed the instructions and added the GTL Framework.  However, when adding this line

```
 private let service = GTLService()
```

I get the use of the unresolved Identifier 'GTLService'  Either there should be a line for importing the service or it seems that the instructions to create  bridging-header.h file may be missing.   I see on the GMail API for Swift page there are instructions to create a bridging header file.

Please can someone who has got the Classroom API working with an iOS app using Swift let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bridging header then add a #import statement for your library. Xcode will auto generate a bridging header for you if you drag in an objective c class file. Do it will any objective c class file.

Expand the framework in the project navigator and look at the header files. Then type like this in the bridging header:

```
#import "NameOfClass.h"
#import "NameOfClass2.h"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've added a bridging header, but I am not sure what import statement I should add, as the documents don't mention the statements, although I suspect something needs to be added.

Comment: Ah yeah I've had that problem too. Expand the framework in the project navigator and look at the header files. then type like this in the bridging header: #import "NameOfClass.h"